# Azure Sotarage em Android - open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-studio, microsoft-azure

Estou com um problema com a API do AZURE STORAGE para Android que é quando tento fazer upload de uma imagem com o seguinte código

```
storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("images");
            // Create the container if it does not exist
            container.createIfNotExists();
            // Create a permissions object
            BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

            // Include public access in the permissions object
            containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);

            // Set the permissions on the container
            container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);
            System.out.println("--- " + pathFile);

            // Create or overwrite the "myimage.jpg" blob with contents from a local file
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(pathFile.toString());

            File source = new File(currImageURI.toString());
            blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source.getAbsolutePath()), source.length());
```

Quando está o System.out.println o resultado é "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1489083183528.jpg" no entanto obtenho logo o erro de seguida

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/images/media/602: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Alguém teve este problema ou sabe porque aparece este path em vez do outro?

Comment: O problema não parece estar na API, e sim no caminho do arquivo. Quando vc faz `getBlockBlobReference()` vc passa um caminho onde ele reclama que o arquivo não está lá.

Comment: O problema reside ai é que a imagem está lá e com aquele caminho...

Comment: Vou buscar o URI através  public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi a minha questão o problema é que estava a passar mal o caminho nesta linha de código CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(pathFile.toString());